# Global mouse event handling similar to MacOsX' build in screenshot functionality

Tags: macos, cocoa, mouseevent, global

I know there are several questions on Stackoverflow regarding global mouse events in MacOsX and I've spent the last hours searching for one that helped me out.

**What I want to create is a functionality that works almost like the build in screenshot functionality of OsX. *(Shift+CMD+4)***

I want to **press a Shortcut** and **activate the mouse listener** with it. Then the **mouseDown event should return one coordinate** and the **mouseRelease event another one**. I then want to make a CGRect from them and the **eventlistener should be deactivated**.

All the codesamples I found give me mouseEvents in a NSView or NSWindow but not global or they give me the location of the mouse coordinate but I've to poll it by myself with a NSTimer. Neither of those is what I need.

As I said: I've spent several hours searching. I've read through many questionthreads and the Apple guide for Cocoa event handling but none of the answers really helped me out.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get the global mouse events using

1) CGEvents. Use CGEventTap().

2) From OS X v 10.6, there is a new method :

```
+ (id)addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:(NSEventMask)mask handler:(void (^)(NSEvent*))block
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at it when I go back to that specific task. It has been on hold for a few weeks now...